# Adobe Flash CC HTML5 Publishing Canvas Drawing Inaccuracy

Tags: html, flash, canvas, publish, createjs

I'll start with the pictures:

[Comparison Of Different Publishing Methods From Flash CC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUJ4g.png)

It seems like there is a huge difference between what's published by through Flash CC HTML5 with CreateJS and what's actually created on the program although they are exact copies (I'm not talking about the pose of the character)

The shapes making up the body parts are all triangles with a solid fill and no stroke.

However, in the HTML5 published versions it looks like all those shapes now have a thin transparent stroke around them in between each other.

Any explanation or official support is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** 
The accepted answer definitely improved some of the problem but unfortunately not enough.

Since it's a **platform limitation**, I decided to work around it by doubling up all the assets of every layer and minutely overlapping them as best as I can.

Here's a link of the work around being implemented if you wanted an update:
[link](http://niboon.x10.mx/walk.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate issue with Canvas. The SWF format actually draws lines with fills on both sides, which enables the SWF (and Flash/Animate IDE) to create seamless edges when drawing shapes with edges that line up. Canvas can not do that, so the antialiasing causes the effect you are seeing.

A *possible* approach would be to cache it at a larger size, and scale it down.

```
var bounds = character.nominalBounds; // Added by Flash export
character.cache(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height, 2);
```

The last parameter is the cache scale factor (in this case it doubles the cache size). It will still draw at the expected scale though.

I made a quick sample to show the difference, and it does help. Note that caching is also a good way to get rid of aliasing on edges. [You can download the sample here](http://playpen.createjs.com/samples/Edges.zip). Uses Adobe Animate 2016.

---

1. Plain shapes exported from Adobe Animate

[image: Plain shapes exported from Adobe Animate]

2. Cached the shape container

[image: Cached the shape container]

3. Doubled the cache size

[image: Doubled the cache size]

---

You also might want to consider dropping in a shape behind it that is closer to the color of the shapes, so if the edges show through, it is not the dark grey background.

Comment: Thank you Lanny for the extremely helpful insight!

There are a couple of things here that aren't explained though.

1) Why does the "Compact Shapes" advanced option create a much wider gap between the shapes as seen in the picture, does this mean that the path encoding might have a significant error?

2)Take a look at the vertical guide lines in white on the background. They also differ on the SWF and the HTML5 version in width. If antialiasing is the issue, why are horizontal lines also affected? The first image your horizontal lines of shapes are not affected but they are in the second.

Comment: Compact shapes *should be* identical. It is possible there are issues with it, but it just translates to moveTo/lineTo calls in the background.

Comment: Your suggestion definitely improved some of the problem but unfortunately not enough.
Since it's a platform limitation, I am just working around by doubling up all the assets of every layer and overlapping them as best as I can.
I need it to be almost perfect because I'm planning to use the assets with my 2D phong shader for my game so the surfaces need to be smooth.
Here's a link of the work around being implemented if you wanted an update:
[link](http://niboon.x10.mx/walk.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Lanny for your input.
You might want to do some tests or file an issue for testing about the difference before and after the "Compact Shapes" path encoding process.